# Why my input, and output elements does not show up in UI?

Tags: r, shiny

i am trying to run, a slider with a histogram using the shiny. But, when i run the code nothing shows up in the browser. Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage( 
  sliderInput(inputId = "num",
              labeel="Choose a number",
              value=25,
              min=1, max=25)#,
 # plotOutput(outputId = "hist")

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

#  output$hist<-renderPlot({ hist(rnorm(1000))  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I tried to present the slider only, by removing the server output, but it also did not work.

Comment: `label` not `labeel`

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled label. Following code works for me.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage( 
  sliderInput(inputId = "num",
              label="Choose a number",
              value=25,
              min=1, max=25)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```